# What's a secure way to message/talk to someone in CM9?

Tags: encryption, privacy, https

I'm using CM9 nightly (20120712 i.e. today).

I need to talk securely, without the chance of eavesdropping, to someone who also has CM9 nightly (not sure how up-to-date but not more than 1 month old).

What apps/webapps can I use to do this? Ideally I would like to be able to talk but messaging/email would be fine.

Are apps like Twitter/Gmail/Gtalk secure end-to-end? I do have HTTPS set up on my account but don't know how far it applies to the mobile version.

But really I am willing to use anything as long as it known to be secure enough to prevent MITM attacks and eavesdropping by unwanted parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following but I don't think this is a definitive answer though it looks close to what I need, secure end-to-end encryption with no chance of snooping/sniffing/MITM.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging#Phone_apps

I wasn't fully aware of OTR though I had heard the term used elsewhere but didn't know the full implications. I think OTR is what I'm looking for.

Still looking for further input though.

Comment: have you tried the apps listed in your link?

Comment: As I discovered them only 10 minutes ago, I haven't had the chance to actually test them yet.

Comment: gotcha. Just wondering. Update your answer if they work the way you want :)

Comment: Will do, but it's a matter of using them to talk to the other person and checking it all works fine. I did use Tor on Android a while back and it looks as if Gibberbot relies on Tor, so it should be fine.

Comment: There are solutions for any android device. Google Talk: [Gibberbot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im) (also on [FDroid](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im)) and for SMS: [TextSecure](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.thoughtcrime.securesms)